# Another Python Scope Question - losing information going into if statement

Tags: python, scope

Not sure if I'm missing something obvious, but here's what is happening:
I have a python 2.4.3 script that contains several RegEx objects. Below one of the regex objects is searching for all matches in a string (tMatchList). Even if tMatchList is not null, it is printing an empty set after the 'if p:' step. This behavior occurs even if it prints correctly before the 'if p:' step. I thought it may have been a scope issue, but everything is declared & contained within one function. I'm not quite seeing how the 'if p:' step is not able to see tMatchList. I am able to print tMatchList after the if statement as well.

```
tMatchList = []
for lines in r:
    linecount += 1

    tMatchList = self._testReplacePDFTag.findall(lines)

    p = self._pdfPathRegex.search(lines)
    print tMatchList   #tMatchList is printing just fine here if it has any elements
    if p:
        print tMatchList #now it's empty, 
                         #even if it printed elements in prior statement
        lines = .....
    else:
        <something else gets done>
    print tMatchList #now it prints again
```

Including entire function definition for those who would like to see it....

```
def FindFilesAndModifyPDFTag(self, inRootDirArg, inRollBackBool):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(inRootDirArg):
        for d in dirs: 
            if d.startswith('.'):#excludes directories that start with '.'
                continue
        for file in files:
            if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == self._fileExt:
                #Backup original. just do it
                shutil.copy2(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(root, file)+"~") 
                r = open(os.path.join(root, file)+"~", "r")
                f = open(os.path.join(root, file), "w")

                linecount = 0
                tMatchList = []
                for lines in r:
                    linecount += 1

                    tMatchList = self._testReplacePDFTag.findall(lines)
                    t = self._testReplacePDFTag.search(lines)

                    #find pdf path(s) in line                    
                    pMatchList = self._pdfPathRegex.findall(lines)
                    p = self._pdfPathRegex.search(lines)
                    #fix the pdf tracking code 
                    print id(tMatchList), "BEFORE"
                    if p:   
                        print id(tMatchList), "INSIDE"
                        lines = self.processPDFTagLine(pMatchList, lines, linecount, file, tMatchList)
                    else:
                        lines = self.processCheckMetaTag(lines, linecount, file)
                        #print id(tMatchList), "INSIDE ELSE"

                         print id(tMatchList), "AFTER"
                         f.writelines(lines)

                f.close()
                r.close()
                os.remove(os.path.join(root, file)+"~")

enter code here
```

Comment: no repro. if nothing is printed in the `else` clause (which might explain confusion) then this could not happen.

Comment: There is code in the else statement - it wasn't relevant to the question so I omitted it.

Comment: I'm not understanding how this is happening.

Comment: What happens if you remove the very first line?

Comment: Getting the same behavior. I actually added that line after seeing this behavior happen because I thought it was related to the scope of for loop for some reason - but of course it couldn't be that easy. It runs the same if that line is there or not.

Comment: Running out of ideas, so download Python 2.4.4 and try again, maybe?

Comment: Ha! I'd love to be doing this with 2.6. I'm restricted by the version running on our servers. I just tried it locally with versions 2.5, 2.6 & 3.1 as well - same issue.

Comment: Wait... is it possible that the first part of the `if` statement is never executing? Try putting a unique print statement in the `else` clause and see if it prints each iteration through the loop.

Comment: That was what SilentGhost was thinking.
If nothing is printed in the else clause, then this problem seems impossible to reproduce.

Comment: It's definitely printing through each iteration. I'm outputting linecounts to see if anything is being skipped. All the line numbers are coming through.

Comment: We need more clues.  Is there more code?

Comment: Not concerning tMatchlist or this issue. The only other code opens the file for reading. this section executes, and then the files are closed. Its maybe six lines of code beyond this block.

Comment: Get the `id()` of `tMatchlist` before the if, and in the if, and after the if, to see if they are the same.

Comment: results from id() (ignore garbage strings - just to keep things straight):
before if : 40206864 MMM
inside if: YYYYYYYY 40206864
after if : 40206864 ZZZ
and if I do this:
 p = self._pdfPathRegex.search(lines)
 #fix the pdf tracking code 
 print id(tMatchList), "MMMMMMMMMMMMMM"
 if p:   
     tMatchList = self._testReplacePDFTag.findall(lines)
it remains empty as if it isn't able to see the string or match the regex in question(even if it works before the if statement)

Comment: @jonny: "Is there more code? " "Not concerning tMatchlist or this issue" Since the problem makes no sense, your assertion appears to be false.

Comment: S.Lott - not interested in your opinion. There are probably plenty of easy question for you out there to focus on. The code for opening and closing the file is NOT related to this specific issue. Your assessment that the problem makes no sense is redundant - why do you think I'm asking the question? Of course it makes no sense.

Comment: @jonny: What specifically does the `processPDFTagLine` method do?

Comment: Right now its simply a stub that prints out the elements that are collected by pMatchList = self._pdfPathRegex.findall(lines) to confirm that the string in question is being passed to the function correctly. At this point it does no manipulation, just a straight print. It returns the line that is passed in as argument 4 (or 5 if you consider self as an arg) unmodified.

Comment: Can you produce a minimum amount of code which reproduces this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what ended up 'fixing' the issue:
I moved the tMatchList findall() line to follow the search. Then I added an 'if t:' statement. Now I am seeing the content of tMatchList inside the 'if p:' statement when I print it out. So problem solved for now, but I'm thinking there is some sort of behavioral concern I'm not aware of concerning the re module(?) or evaluating an empty list object.

```
#original code ....
linecount += 1

#this is modified section
t = self._testReplacePDFTag.search(lines)
if t:
    tMatchList = self._testReplacePDFTag.findall(lines)

#end modified section

pMatchList = self._pdfPathRegex.findall(lines)
```

Comment: Another problem i discovered yesterday after all that was that the t value was only getting set once. If i tried resetting the list inside the 'for lines in r:' loop to fix this issue, it was always empty. I ended up blowing up this routine and starting from scratch. This will be the accepted answer to the specific problem above, but the general issue was not truly addressed in my solution(why the values from the list seemed to disappear going into the 'if p:' statement)

Answer (score 0):

The `findall` may not create a list object.  If it is some kind of generator function, then it has a value which is "consumed" by traversing the results once.

After consuming the results yielded by this function, there are no more results.

```
tMatchList = self._testReplacePDFTag.findall(lines)

p = self._pdfPathRegex.search(lines)
print tMatchList   #tMatchList is printing just fine here if it has any elements
if p:
    print tMatchList #now it's empty,
```

Try this.

```
tMatchList = list( self._testReplacePDFTag.findall(lines) )
```

Comment: That's very possible.
Wouldn't that mean that the generator-object has a ____str____ method that also traverses the results?
Edit: I don't think this is the case now, because re.findall always returns a list of strings.

Comment: jonny's question states that tMatchList DOES still have elements, though, because it prints just fine after the `if` statement.

Comment: from the documentation:
re.findall(pattern, string[, flags]):
    Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings